# Not receiving opsgenie created alerts

Tags: opsgenie

I'm working on implementing opsgenie for the first time, with a new airflow instance. I have been unable to receive alerts so far, even though everything seems to be correctly set up.

I already have my account/team and integrations (slack and api) set. I already configured the opsgenie conection in airflow (using the slack api key as password). An I already added the opsgenie hook to my code.

It all seems to work ok. According to the airflow logs, the opsgenie genie request is correctly sent. I even get responses like this:

```
Sending 'POST' to url: https://api.opsgenie.com/v2/alerts
<Response [202]>
{'result': 'Request will be processed', 'took': 0.007, 'requestId': '65f2a665-40ea-4173-967e-xxxxxxxxxx'}
```

If I search for the request id, I get this response:

```
{
"data": {
"success": true,
"action": "Create",
"processedAt": "2023-01-03T16:40:03.08Z",
"integrationId": "xxx",
"isSuccess": true,
"status": "Created alert",
"alertId": "xxx",
"alias": "ECO_OPSGENIE_ALERTS-send_opsgenie_alerts-20230103"
},
"took": 0.004,
"requestId": "65f2a665-40ea-4173-967e-xxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

However, NO alerts are ever sent, and I can't see them anywhere in the opsgenie alerts section. And of course I also get bothing on slack or on the opsgenie app.

If I create a "manual" alert using the opsgenie app, I do get slack and app alerts... but nothing using the API.

I also tried directly from postman, but same thing: no alerts are sent, even though the response says they were correctly created.

Any idea what could be causing this and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if anyone will need this, but I solved it. I had to add this parameter to the request's body:

"responders": [
{
"name": team_name,
"type": "team"
}
]

team_name is the name of my configured team in opsgenie. That's it. Now it's all working.